# MPI + CUDA AWARE, concurrents kernels and MPI_Sendrecv

Tags: concurrency, cuda, mpi, profiler, mvapich2

During my work, I've found a little problem. Now I'm using MVAPICH-GDR-2.05 and Open MPI 1.7.4 with CUDA 6.0.

I'm working on the exchange of non contiguous elements between GPUs (like the columns of a matrix), and I'm trying to run two kernel's (one for scatter and one for gather) and a communication with `MPI_Sendrecv` between two GPUs concurrently.

I've used the CUDA profiler (nvprof) to see what my program is doing, and I've seen strange things:

- With Open MPI 1.7.4, I've 3 cuda streams works concurrently.
- With MVAPICH-gdr-2.05, I've two concurrent kernel's and the `MPI_Sendrecv` is not concurrent with them.

Do you know why `MPI_Sendrecv` in MVAPICH does this?

This is my pseudocode:

```
// creation and initialization of streams
cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
cudaStreamCreateWithFlags( stream1, cudaStreamNonBlocking )
cudaStreamCreateWithFlags( stream2, cudaStreamNonBlocking )

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// 1) --> gather of the first chunk
gather_kernel <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream1 >>> ( ... )
cudaStreamSynchronize(stream1)

// 2) --> gather of the second chunk
//    --> communication of the first chunk
gather_kernel <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream1 >>> ( ... )
MPI_Sendrecv( ... )
cudaStreamSynchronize(stream1)

// 3) --> scatter of the chunk (ii)
//    --> gather of the chunk (ii+2)
//    --> communication of the chunk (ii+1)
// K is the number of chunk
for ( ii=0; ii<K-2; ii++ ){
    scatter_kernel <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream2 >>> ( ... )
    gather_kernel  <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream1 >>> ( ... )
    MPI_Sendrecv( ... )
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream2)
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream1)
}

// 4) --> scatter of the penultimate chunk
//    --> communication of the last chunk
scatter_kernel <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream2 >>> ( ... )
MPI_Sendrecv( ... )
cudaStreamSynchronize(stream2)

// 5) --> scatter of the last chunk
scatter_kernel <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream2 >>> ( ... )
cudaStreamSynchronize(stream2)
```

And these are the two profiler's screenshoot:

- [MVAPICH 2.05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZKKM.png)
- [Open MPI 1.7.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RHz6.png)

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet :(
Do you have any idea?

Comment: My question is how to make MPI_Send work on a specific cuda stream.

Comment: I think you can't choose specific CUDA stream for operations that are performed by CPU, but maybe I wrong. If you find the way to use a specific stream with CPU operations please let me know :)

Comment: Direct GPU to GPU copy through infiniband should be able to bind to a stream, it doesn't involve CPU.

Comment: Yes I know, but the MPI_Send instruction is in "host" code not in a CUDA kernel...